# C#: Outputting the cell data in an excel worksheet based on the row and column input

Tags: c#, excel

So, what I'm trying to do essentially is search an excel worksheet for data based on the row-column input from the user.
1. take 2 user input values (row & column)
2. Search row 1 (of the worksheet) for the user's row value input.
3. Search column A (of the excel worksheet) for the user's column value input.
4. Output the data at the cell location. e.g. cell D5.

I've been looking at a lot of different posts but nothing that seems to help with this. 
By the way, it doesn't necessary have to be .xls, it can be .csv also.

All help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there's a big difference between a `xls` file and a `csv` file - just because Excel will open both doesn't mean they are the same.

However, you should be able to make use of the Excel Interop services to access the specific cell you want from the user data.

For example, something like this:

```
String value = (String)(excelWorksheet.Cells[rowNum, colNum] as Excel.Range).Value;
```

It may also be possible to simply access the value with

```
var value = excelWorksheet.cells[rowNum, colNum];
```

My memory on that is a little rusty but I think that would also work - though of course it no longer has a type and would need casting for further work.

That would give you the value at the cell location provided by the user.

If you want to use cell references (e.g. D5), then you can convert a number given by the user into a column heading easily enough and combine it with the row reference. There's a tutorial on converting an int into an Excel column heading here: http://frasergreenroyd.com/convert-a-number-to-an-excel-column-heading/